# Plaid + Stripe ACH (Developer Mode): Do I need to use a stripe production key

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

Short story, I am able to successfully use the Plaid API (connected to my stripe account) to get a stripe bank token in sandbox mode.

From there, I can add that bank token to a customers profile in my stripe account (again in test mode).

Now I'm trying to use the plaid developer key instead of sandbox.  I'm able to verify my real world bank account via plaid and get a bank token back, but when i try to add that token to my stripe account I get the following error:

**Invalid Request: No such token: 'btok_xxxxxxxxxxxDequ'; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.**

This seems to indicate when calling the Stripe API I need to use the production stripe key instead of the test key.

Since stripe doesn't have a "developer" mode like plaid, my question is what happens if I do this?  Does the bank account get added to a real customer account (I assume it does).

AND if I attempt to make a charge using this bank token I got back from plaid via developer mode, will this make an actual charge in stripe?  or does stripe know the difference and not make an actual charge (withdrawal) for my bank account?

I tried to go through plaid documentation, but there is very little information I could extract about the developer mode.

Thank you for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: As I understand it, Plaid's Development environment produces live banking tokens that if used with Stripe's live mode API will result in real charges/payments. The difference between Development & Production with Plaid is the limit on the objects you can create. This is briefly mention [here](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid) (step 5) on the Stripe documentation.

Comment: @JonathanSteele. thank you for the reply.  So i've requested "production" access a couple weeks ago for my employer, but Plaid has not given me a response one way or another.  Radio silence.  From what you described, it sounds like we should go live with the "developer" key first.  I'm wondering if that is a requirement before we get a "production" key.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. But you should ok initially within Development environment assuming low volume.